# How can I create a file for each value of a column in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

I have a codelist with hundreds of Diseases, and multiple codes for each Disease. How can I create and export a separate .csv file for each Disease, and save it using the Diseases' name?

```
Disease <- as.character(c("HIV","HIV", "HIV", "HIV", "anaemia", "anaemia", "anaemia", "Chronic Kidney Disease", "Chronic Kidney Disease"))
Code <- c(123, 432, 567, 876, 433, 096, 543, 912, 456)
codelist <- data.frame(Disease, Code)
codelist
                 Disease Code
1                    HIV  123
2                    HIV  432
3                    HIV  567
4                    HIV  876
5                anaemia  433
6                anaemia   96
7                anaemia  543
8 Chronic Kidney Disease  912
9 Chronic Kidney Disease  456
```

E.g.:

```
> HIV
  Disease Code
1     HIV  123
2     HIV  432
3     HIV  567
4     HIV  876
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a base R approach:

```
codelist.lst <- split(codelist, codelist$Disease)
fnames <- paste0(names(codelist.lst), ".csv")
lapply(seq(codelist.lst), function(x) write.csv(codelist.lst[[x]], file=fnames[x]))
```

Comment: It works until a certain point, then it stops: Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
When I open the warning message: Warning messages:
1: In write.csv(codelists[[i]], paste0(names(codelists)[i],  ... :
  attempt to set 'col.names' ignored
2: In write.csv(codelists[[i]], paste0(names(codelists)[i],  ... :
  attempt to set 'sep' ignored
3: In write.csv(codelists[[i]], paste0(names(codelists)[i],  ... :
  attempt to set 'dec' ignored
4: In write.csv(codelists[[i]], paste0(names(codelists)[i],  ... :

Comment: Try the modified code. The original works on my operating system (MacOs) for your example, but I did not add a file extension which may have created a problem. The modified code creates a variable with the file names so that you can check to see if a file name (disease) contains a character that is not valid as part of a file name (e.g. "/" or "\"). The `lapply` function lists the number of each file as it proceeds so that will tell you where things are failing.